# How to create a generic process that read in a tab delimited file, and return a generic Map from it

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

Almost every project that I work will have some sort of tab delimited file that I need to read in and return a lookup Map of it. I find myself rewrite the same method over and over again. I want to create something more generic so I don't have to do copy and paste code all the time. From the below code, I only change **line 9, and 16-19**. So I only change the `Map<key, value>`, and the implementation of how I want to input data into the Map. Is there a way make a generic process from this, so every time I want to invoke this method, all I need is to provide my implementation of how I want to input data into Map, and somehow change the Map to a more generic type as well.

```
1. public Map<String, PackageLog> readAllLogsIntoMap(File file){
2.      if (!file.exists())
3.      {
4.          return new HashMap <String, PackageLog> ();
5.      }
6.      BufferedReader reader = null;
7.      FileReader fileReader = null;
8.      String data = null;
9.      Map <String, PackageLog> resultMap = new HashMap <String, PackageLog> ();
10.     try
11.     {
12.         fileReader = new FileReader(file);
13.         reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
14.         while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null)
15.         {
16.             PackageLog pl = new PackageLog(data);
17.             if(!pl.getPdfName().equals("")){
18.                 resultMap.put(pl.getPdfName(), pl);
19.             }
20.         }
21.     } catch(Exception e){
22.         
23.     }
24.     finally
25.     {
26.         try{
27.             if (reader != null) reader.close();
28.             if (fileReader != null) fileReader.close();
29.         }catch(IOException ioe){
30.             
31.         }
32.     }
33.     return resultMap;
34. }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put this method in an abstract Util class. Use generics.
2. Delegate on abstract methods the logic to perform on lines 9 and 16-19.
3. Define these abstract methods in the uses of this class

For instance:

```
public abstract class ReaderUtil<K, V> {

 protected abstract Map<K, V> newMap(); 
 protected abstract void doThings(String data, Map<K, V> resultMap);

 public Map<K, V> readAllLogsIntoMap(File file){
      if (!file.exists()){
          return newMap();
      }
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      FileReader fileReader = null;
      String data = null;
      Map <K, V> resultMap = newMap();
      try {
         fileReader = new FileReader(file);
         reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
         while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
             doThings(data, resultMap);
         }
     } catch(Exception e){

     }
     finally{
         try{
             if (reader != null) reader.close();
             if (fileReader != null) fileReader.close();
         } catch(IOException ioe){

         }
     }
     return resultMap;
 }
}
```

And a possible use:

```
ReaderUtil<String, PackageLog> reader = new ReaderUtil<String, PackageLog>(){
    protected Map<String, PackageLog> newMap() { 
        return new HashMap<String, PackageLog>(); 
    }
    protected void doThings(String data, Map<String, PackageLog> resultmap){
        PackageLog pl = new PackageLog(data);
        if(!pl.getPdfName().equals("")){
            resultMap.put(pl.getPdfName(), pl);
        }
    }
};
Map<String, PackageLog> myMap = reader.readAllLogsIntoMap();
```

Take into account you only need the `newMap()` method if you want to provide different map implementations. You could well do `new HashMap<K, V>()` inside the generified class.

You might also want to define hook methods (overridable, maybe-empty methods) for handling exceptions.

Comment: This looks awesome. I just have one question for you. Do we really need method `newMap()`. So when we check `if (!file.exists())`, can we just `return new HashMap <K, V> ();`? Is there anything wrong with this, Xavi?

Comment: ohh I see, you did answer my above question. However, i dont understand what you mean by this `Take into account you only need the newMap() method if you want to provide different map implementations`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Indeed, as stated in the answer, it would be only necessary if implementations might want to provide different implementations of `Map` (`HashMap`, `TreeMap` and so on). Even in this case it could be reduced to a `protected abstract Class getMapClass()`, or even a generic, and perform instantiation through reflection.

Comment: The code that you showed work great, is it possible to even generalized to the point that it can return a List<> as well. Right now it only return Map<K, V>. I can make this into another question if you want to.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following.

```
public interface LookupKey<K, T> {
    K keyFor(T t );
}

public <K, T> Map<K, T> readAllLogsIntoMap(File file, Class<T> tClass, LookupKey<K, T> lookupKey) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    Map<K, T> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, T>();
    if (!file.exists())
        return resultMap;
    try {
        Constructor<T> tConstructor = tClass.getConstructor(String.class);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String data;
        while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            T t = tConstructor.newInstance(data);
            K key = lookupKey.keyFor(t);
            if (key != null)
                resultMap.put(key, t);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Comment: @Peter: is it possible to even generalized to the point that it can return a List<> as well. Right now it only return Map<K, V>. I can make this into another question if you want to

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use are CSV parser, e.g. http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Harry, considering that Java does not have a nice support for type typles like, say, the D programming language, you have to refactor your method to have signature like: `public Map<String, Object[]> csvToMap(File argFile, char argSeparator, Class[]) {}` . Then, you would invoke it like: `mymap = csvToMap("/tmp/some.log", ';', { Date.class, String.class, Double.class});` . This invocation may be used to parse a CSV file containing lines like `2011-11-23;Some Name;232.22`

Comment: Actually, I will code this function for my own lib. It will be useful for all cases when all I need is to parse a CSV file and populate some collection object with data. :)